# Strange vertical row in a bootstrap 4 container

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am inserting simple html pages made with bootstrap 4 into a wordpress project. 
I'm using the `container` class to the divs that contain the contents. 
The pages work very well, if it were not for a vertical line that appears to me along the whole page, made up as follows:
[image]
On another page:
[image]

I tried on the usual page to put a piece of css doing so:

```
* {
   border: none;
}
```

or

```
.container {
   border: none;
}
```

But I see that nothing has changed, so I can't imagine what it is. 
Here are the page links:
[page 1](https://www2.casailaria.it/progetto/tempistica/)
[page 2](https://www2.casailaria.it/cosa-facciamo/festeggia-con-noi/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Use right mouse in browser and check the properties, should be easy to find

Comment: Already tried. I can't staple it.

Comment: @Memmo link of website (così controllo)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini https://www2.casailaria.it/progetto/tempistica/ and https://www2.casailaria.it/cosa-facciamo/festeggia-con-noi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being added by custom style from Divi here:

```
   @media (min-width: 981px){
    #main-content .container:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    content: "";
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are great! I tried to staple it too but I couldn't! Warm congratulations!